# Get and display the values for product attribute in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, product

In WooCommerce, I have this code to show product attributes slugs on archives pages like **shop** pages :

```
if (!function_exists('shop_attributes_in_loop')) {
    function shop_attributes_in_loop(){
        global $product;
        $attributes = $product->get_attributes();
        if(!empty($attributes)){
            $attribute_single = array_keys($attributes);
            $myArray = array();
            echo '<div class="product_attributes">';
            foreach ($attribute_single as $attribute => $value) {
                $myArray[] = ucfirst($value);
            }
            echo implode(', ', $myArray).'</div>';
        }
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'shop_attributes_in_loop');
```

They only show atributes field name  as **`pa_size`**, **`pa_color`**

How can I get and display the values for that product attributes (like **`2kg`**, **`3kg`** or **`blue`**, **`green`**)?

Thanks.

Comment: It is very difficult to know what you are asking as it is currently written.

Comment: this code shows the name of the atributte field.

i would like the code to show the atribute values (not the name of the fields)

clear now ?

Answer (score 3):

It's simple with this code (Example 1):

```
function nt_product_attributes() {
global $product;
    if ( $product->has_attributes() ) {

        $attributes = ( object ) array (
        'color'              => $product->get_attribute( 'pa_color' ),
        'size'            => $product->get_attribute( 'pa_size' ),
        );
    return $attributes;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$attributes = nt_product_attributes();
echo $attributes->color;
echo $attributes->size;
```

OR (Example 2)

```
function nt_product_attributes() {
global $product;
    if ( $product->has_attributes() ) {

        $attributes = array (
        'color'              => $product->get_attribute('pa_color'),
        'size'            => $product->get_attribute('pa_size'),
        );
    return $attributes;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$attributes = nt_product_attributes();
echo $attributes['color'];
echo $attributes['size'];
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the attributes values you need to use [**`get_terms()`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/), with inside as argument your WC product attribute slug as **`pa_size`**, **`pa_color`**… So to display the corresponding values for each attribute you will need a second foreach loop.

So your code could be something like this:

```
if (!function_exists('shop_attributes_in_loop')) {
    function shop_attributes_in_loop(){
        global $product;

        //Getting product attributes
        $product_attributes = $product->get_attributes();

        if(!empty($product_attributes)){

            //Getting product attributes slugs
            $product_attribute_slugs = array_keys($product_attributes);
            $count_slug = 0;

            echo '<div class="product_attributes">';

            foreach ($product_attribute_slugs as $product_attribute_slug){
                $count_slug++;

                // Removing "pa_" from attribute slug and adding a cap to first letter
                $attribute_name =  ucfirst( str_replace('pa_', '', $product_attribute_slug) );
                echo $attribute_name . ' (';

##  ===>  ===>  // Getting the product attribute values
                $attribute_values = get_terms($product_attribute_slug);
                $count_value = 0;
                foreach($attribute_values as $attribute_value){
                    $count_value++;
                    $attribute_name_value = $attribute_value->name; // name value
                    $attribute_slug_value = $attribute_value->slug; // slug value
                    $attribute_slug_value = $attribute_value->term_id; // ID value

                    // Displaying HERE the "names" values for an attribute
                    echo $attribute_name_value;
                    if($count_value != count($attribute_values)) echo ', ';
                }
                if($count_slug != count($product_attribute_slugs)) echo '), ';
                else echo ').';
            }
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
} 
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'shop_attributes_in_loop');
```

and will display for example something like this (for name values of **`pa_color`** and **`pa_size`**):

```html
Color (Black, Blue, Green), Size (30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40, 42, 44).
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme or in any plugin file).*

**This code is tested and works.**

Comment: Took me longer than it should have to find a working solution, but yours did, thanks !